# Lighting reacting wrong on object

Tags: unity

[image]

Long story short, A and B are the same object just rotated 180
The area light is for some reason also "flipped"
I tried playing with the generated lightmap and turning it off, changing resolutions, and changing textures.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide us with a set of scene setup instructions sufficient to reproduce this issue, starting from a new, empty project? Once we can get hands-on with a minimal sample, we can test potential solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: A wild-ass guess is that it's related to lightmap baking. Eg If the object is marked "static", its lighting information is saved at build-time. But ... As has been said already, you'll need to give us far more context to help you. Start again and assume we know nothing about your project, goals, setup or anything else.